# How reuse flux mono value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Consider a code:

```
WebClient webClient = ... ;

public Mono<MyWrapper> someFunction () {
    Mono<MyDto> mono = webClient.get()
       .uri("myUrl")
       .retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(MyDto.class);

    Mono<FirstDto> first = mono.map(dto -> {...});
    Mono<SecondDto> second = mono.map(dto -> {...}); //<- connection closed error here

    return Mono.zip(first, second).map(zip -> {
        return new MyWrapper(first, second);
    });
}
```

Second `map` operation leads to connection closed error. I suppose that flux tried to send new request. (Does it or not?)
Second is there a way to `map` mono twice: to one type and another one **without** sending new request?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using compose?

```
Mono<MyWrapper> mono = webClient.get()
        .uri("myUrl")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(MyDto.class)
        .compose(dto -> dto
                .zip(dto.map(dto -> {...}), dto.map(dto -> {...})))
        .map(MyWrapper::new);
```

API:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: Does really the `compose()` method (still) exist? The link does not work as expected.